# determine the position of a number after removing numbers containing 4 (python)

Tags: python

The question is like this: Starting from 1, if I give you a number, say 6, I want you to find out what number is in position 6, after removing number containing 4. Result: 7

My script is like this:

```
x = int(input('What position do you want? '))
y = 0 #variable to iterate until y = x
z = 1 #count how many iteration
while y < x:
    y_str = str(y)
    if '4' in y_str:
        z += 1
        continue
    else:
        y += 1
        z += 1
print(z)
```

But I don't know why the code don't stop. What's wrong with my code

Comment: you're not changing `y` when it contains 4: the loop runs forever.

Comment: so for x = 26, answer = 23 ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How can I fix this problem? It seems it can't be solved by changing the script slightly.

Comment: @AnkushRathi Should be the other way round, I give you 23, then position at 23 is the number 26, since 4, 14 and 24 have been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
x = int( input( 'What position do you want? ' ) )
y = 0
z = 0
while y < x:
    if '4' in str(y):
        z += 1
    y += 1
print (z+y)
```

if you want to also go the additional skipped steps alternate the while with this:

```
while y < x + z:
```

---

<sub>*your old code wasn't working, since your loop was stuck at the moment, when it first encountered something containing the '4'. You then were not incrementing the `y`, which then resulted in finding the '4' over and over again while further not incrementing `y`.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

your program will go into an infinite loop when it **first** encounters a number which contains digit `4` because in the following code portion you are not updating `y` and `continu`ing.

```
if '4' in y_str:
    z += 1
    continue
```